# Is there something about a string with an exclamation mark that prevent Python from string interning?

Tags: python, string

Consider the two scenarios:

```
>>> a = "python is cool!"
>>> b = "python is cool!"
>>> a is b
False
```

and

```
>>> a = "python"
>>> b = "python"
>>> a is b
True   # a and b refer to the same object!
```

I am wondering why string interning occurs in the second scenario but not the first. Is is due to the exclamation mark or the general length? Thanks!

Comment: I fail to see how having an exclamation mark induces difference objects. I do understand that the "is" operator compares objects, but what is it about the exclamation mark that changes this? If I removed the exclamation mark from the first chunk of code, it evaluates as true!

Comment: Is a space the same thing as an exclamation mark?

Comment: Removing the exclamation mark wouldn't be enough to trigger interning in CPython. You most likely did something else different in the exclamation-mark-removed case to trigger a different optimization, bytecode constant deduplication, which looks a lot like interning but is a different mechanism.

Comment: Possible candidates would be putting the assignments on the same line or putting the code in a script or a function.